# using RK4 method for a 2nd order differential equation (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, ode

[image: 1]

This is my code. My thetaDot values seem to give a fairly decent representation, but my values for theta just get exponentially bigger or smaller. Please could someone give me some advice?

I have tried using an initial value for theta, defined as theta0. When passing theta0 to my second call of the RK4 function, I get some reasonable looking values, however this cannot be correct, as theta0 does not change value, and isn't affected by thetaDot.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The code should be included as code not an image.

Comment: You need to solve a system as system. Your `thetaDot` procedure is incomprehensible, what is the `thetaDot` value inside there, did you attempt to pull a Münchhausen trick? See my link collection on [second order DE to be solved by RK4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176684/how-to-implement-a-runge-kutta-method-rk4-for-a-second-order-differential-equa)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.